# How to implement Autocomplete using Trie with a HashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, autocomplete, hashmap, trie

Here below is the code with HashMap implementation of Trie. But I am not sure how to implement the autocomplete part. I see how people have used LinkedList to implement Trie, but I want to understand with HashMap. Any help appreciated. I have pasted the code below for my Trie.

Is there a way to look for a prefix, then go to the end of the prefix and look for its children and return them back as strings? And if so, how to achieve using HashMap implementation. Or shouldn't I even do this with HashMap and go for LinkedList. And I am not sure, why one is better than the other?

```
public class TrieNode {

    Map<Character, TrieNode> children;
    boolean isEndOfWord;

    public TrieNode() {
        isEndOfWord = false;
        children = new HashMap<>();
    }

}

public class TrieImpl {

    private TrieNode root;

    public TrieImpl() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    // iterative insertion into Trie Data Structure
    public void insert(String word) {
        if (searchTrie(word))
            return;

        TrieNode current = root;
        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            TrieNode node = current.children.get(ch);
            if(node == null) {
                node = new TrieNode();
                current.children.put(ch, node);
            }
            current = node;
        }
        current.isEndOfWord = true;
    }

    // search iteratively
    public boolean searchTrie(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        for(int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            TrieNode node = current.children.get(ch);
            if(node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = node;
        }
        return current.isEndOfWord;
    }


    // delete a word recursively
    private boolean deleteRecursive(TrieNode current, String word, int index) {

        if(index == word.length()) {
            if(!current.isEndOfWord) {
                return false;
            }
            current.isEndOfWord = false;
            return current.children.size() == 0;
        }
        char ch = word.charAt(index);
        TrieNode node = current.children.get(ch);

        if(node == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean shouldDeleteCurrentNode = deleteRecursive(node, word, index+1);

        if(shouldDeleteCurrentNode) {
            current.children.remove(ch);
            return current.children.size() == 0;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // calling the deleteRecursively function
    public boolean deleteRecursive(String word) {
        return deleteRecursive(root, word, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrieImpl obj = new TrieImpl();

        obj.insert("amazon");
        obj.insert("amazon prime");
        obj.insert("amazing");
        obj.insert("amazing spider man");
        obj.insert("amazed");
        obj.insert("alibaba");
        obj.insert("ali express");
        obj.insert("ebay");
        obj.insert("walmart");

        boolean isExists = obj.searchTrie("amazing spider man");
        System.out.println(isExists);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was in hurry finding some other solution here, but this is
>   interesting question.

Answering this-

> Is there a way to look for a prefix, then go to the end of the prefix
>   and look for its children and return them back as strings?

Yes, why not, if you  have prefix `ama` ,now go to your `searchTrie` method,  and when you are done and out of the loop. then, you have `current` variable pointing to `a`(last character from `ama`)

you can then write a method as below -

```
    public List<String> getPrefixStrings(TrieNode current){
           // DO DFS here and put all character with isEndOfWord = true in the list
           // keep on recursing to this same method and adding to the list
           // then return the list

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhs, I will try that approach.